# Windows Server 2008 GPO Not Mapping Drives?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, mappeddrive

I have 2 servers.

### Server 1:

Linux server running Samba, that has a share called "Common".

### Server 2:

Windows Server 2008. I created a GPO that maps drive R: to `\\LINUXSERVER\Common`. I set it to "Reconnect" and chose the "Create" option. I then run `gpupdate /force`. The client computer, after I log off and then logged back on, does not have the drive map show up. Why is this?

As per request, I attempted to post GPResult, but due to a 30000 character limitation, I was unable to post all of it in this box. However, I posted the most relevant part. Is there another way to post the entire GPResult?

```
 Group Policy Results
 Preferences
 Windows Settings
 Drive Maps
 Drive Map (Drive: S)
 The following settings have applied to this object. Within this category, settings nearest the top of the report are the prevailing settings when resolving conflicts.
 S:Winning GPO  CableTest General Settings

 Result: Failure (Error Code: 0x80070035)
 GeneralAction  Create

 PropertiesLetter   S
 Location   \\192.168.1.200\Software
 Reconnect  Enabled
 Label as   Software
 Use first available    Disabled
 Hide/Show this drive   Show
 Hide/Show all drives   No change

 Drive Map (Drive: W)
 The following settings have applied to this object. Within this category, settings nearest the top of the report are the prevailing settings when resolving conflicts.
 W:Winning GPO  Common_Maps

 Result: Failure (Error Code: 0x80070056)
 GeneralAction  Create

 PropertiesLetter   W
 Location   \\LINUXSERVER\Software
 Reconnect  Enabled
 Label as   Software
 Use first available    Disabled
 Connect as %username%
 Hide/Show this drive   Show
 Hide/Show all drives   Show

 Drive Map (Drive: X)
 The following settings have applied to this object. Within this category, settings nearest the top of the report are the prevailing settings when resolving conflicts.
 X:Winning GPO  Common_Maps

 Result: Failure (Error Code: 0x80070056)
 GeneralAction  Create

 PropertiesLetter   X
 Location   \\LINUXSERVER\Common
 Reconnect  Enabled
 Label as   Common
 Use first available    Disabled
 Connect as %username%
 Hide/Show this drive   Show
 Hide/Show all drives   Show

 Drive Map (Drive: R)
 The following settings have applied to this object. Within this category, settings nearest the top of the report are the prevailing settings when resolving conflicts.
 R:Winning GPO  Common_Maps

 Result: Failure (Error Code: 0x80070056)
 GeneralAction  Create

 PropertiesLetter   R
 Location   \\LINUXSERVER\The Employee Handbook
 Reconnect  Enabled
 Label as   Company Policies
 Use first available    Disabled
 Connect as %username%
 Hide/Show this drive   Show
 Hide/Show all drives   Show
```

Comment: The client computer is running Windows 7. The GPO is linked to an OU called CableTest. I do not know if the GPO is being processed by the client computer. And I have not used GPRESULT.

Comment: Try changing the group policy to replace instead of create. This should replace any exisiting drive maps

Comment: @MilesErickson: The computer is in the CableTest OU. The Computer is in a sub-OU of CableTest called "Computers".

Comment: @FunkySi: I've tried Replace, Update, and Create, none of which worked.

Comment: @user1827233 You need to do some diagnostics. Have you checked the Event Log. And have you checked GPResult yet? If the GPO is not even being applied then it's never ever going to work.

Comment: @user1827233 You're getting downvotes because your question is incomplete. More information is needed before we can help you, or before you can help yourself.

Comment: I downvoted due to the lack of research effort, specifically:  " I do not know if the GPO is being processed by the client computer. And I have not used GPRESULT."

Comment: I do not know how to tell if the GPO is being processed. As for GPRESULT. I will post the result of it in a few minutes after it's finished processing.

Comment: Do you have "Run in logged-on user's security context (user policy option)" checked or unchecked for your Drive Map Preference?  Counter-intuitively, on my setup it actually has to be unchecked in order for the drive to be mapped.

Answer (score 2):

GPP Drive Mappings apply to User objects, not Computer objects. You need to link the drive mapping GPO to the OU where your User objects are OR you need to configure Loopback Policy Processing on the GPO linked to the OU where the Computer objects are.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a sub-OU called "Users" where all the User objects are stored. So should I link it there? Also, I am unclear as to the difference between a GPP and a GPO.

Comment: Yes, assuming you created your policy correctly, it should be linked to the OU where the users are. GPP - group policy preference, GPO - group policy object. GPP's are part of the GPO. Google and Microsoft documentation should be able to explain the rest. If you don't understand how they work, you really should try to learn before using them.

Comment: Where is this sub-OU? Under the Computer OU or under the domain root?

Comment: @Rex: I linked the OU where the user objects are, but it did not working

Comment: Log off and back on. Then run GPRESULTS and post the results here.

Comment: @joeqwerty: The top level OU is called CableTest which has 2 sub-OUs. One is called "Users" and the other is called "Computers". The CableTest OU is under the domain root.

Comment: Also, check that the server name can be resolved and that the user has the correct Share and Folder permissions.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It took me a while to format the GPResults. In regards to the server name, it can be resolved and the access rights are correct. Also, if I were to map via a log on script, I can successfully. However, as per design requirements, it has be done via the drive map policy preference.